# mergeDebugResources FAILED

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, apk

Getting below error when i run command as :
ionic build --prod && ionic capacitor sync android && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug && cd ..

Error :

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find :peb-lib-android-x:.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - file:/Users/apple/Rekart/Customer-App/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs/peb-lib-android-x.aar
> - file:/Users/apple/Rekart/Customer-App/android/app/libs/peb-lib-android-x.aar
> Required by:
> project :app > project :easebuzz-capacitorjs-sdk

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
61 actionable tasks: 61 executed

i want create debug apk for testing .